# Why WhenAll waits indefinetely with multiple pings?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, ping

My application needs to ping all possible IP addresses in a network. Since the IP list is big (about 4000 entries) I decided to do the ping asynchronously to speed up the process. The code I wrote initially seemed to work fine, but somehow when I tried it yesterday it didn't work as expected anymore (maybe after some .NET updates? I don't really know).

Here is how my code works: from the list of IP addresses I created a list of tasks (one for each IP) and then passed the list of tasks to WhenAll to wait for all ping requests to finish. The problem is that sometimes WhenAll waits indefinitely (I checked it with the debugger and I saw that some of the tasks passed to WhenAll always remained in the State "Waiting for activation"). The strange thing is that sometimes (about 2 times in 3 tests) it works as expected and all tasks completes.

Here is the code I used:

```
    public static async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync(List<IPAddress> ips, int timeout)
     {
         var pingTasks = ips.Select(ip =>
         {
             using (Ping ping = new Ping())
             {
                 return ping.SendPingAsync(ip, timeout);
             }
         });
    
         var results = await Task.WhenAll(pingTasks);
    
         return results.ToList();
     }
```

Any hint on what the problem could be?

Comment: Note that you dispose `ping` before the `Task` returned from `SendPingAsync` completes, *but* you're not using `ping` *anyway*, so your second bug avoids the first one... Maybe this issue is that you're not disposing the (second) `new Ping()`? I'm not sure what unmanaged resources it uses.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that I mixed two versions of the code I made (I tried it in many ways). I will edit the question to remove the second Ping that is not necessary. But how to correctly dispose the Ping instance after the Task returned?

Comment: In edited version of your code you dispose `ping` potentially before `SendPingAsync` completes, leading to unpredictable behavior. Just make anonymous function you pass to Select async - `async ip => ... return await ping.SendPingAsync`

Comment: Also see [eliding `async`/`await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is potentially that you're disposing `ping` before the `Task` returned from `SendPingAsync` might have completed. This will be racey, which might explain why you're seeing this happen unpredictably.

Try awaiting that `Task` before disposing `ping`:

```
public static async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync(List<IPAddress> ips, int timeout)
{
    var pingTasks = ips.Select(async ip =>
    {
        using (Ping ping = new Ping())
        {
            return await ping.SendPingAsync(ip, timeout);
        }
    });

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(pingTasks);

    return results.ToList();
}
```

Comment: You're losing parallelism when awaiting `SendPingAsync` don't you? This is the purpose of `WhenAll`

Comment: First example won't compile, while second will fail, because `Ping` class doesn't support concurrent pings from the same instance.

Comment: @Phate01 No. If I had a loop over `ips` and the `await` in a loop then you'd be right, but this is creating an `async` function (which contains the `using` and `await`), calling it multiple times, then awaiting the resulting `Tasks` in one go

Comment: @Evk Fixed the missing `return`. I wasn't sure about the concurrentness, hence the caveat. Removed.

Comment: How to invoke your code(method) ??? as i am not getting the results!!

Comment: How to invoke your code(method) ??? as i am not getting the results!!

Comment: Thank you, this was surely the problem as now it seems to always work fine. This also explains the strange behaviour I was having, as you mentioned.

Comment: @Ori how to invoke and get result from the above method???

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz Asking just once is enough, and a single `?` or `!` is generally sufficient. [Here's an example of calling it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Jvo7P)

Comment: apologies for my irrational behavior. but why this statement hangs

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz I don't know what you mean by "why this statement hangs". See my link for an example of this code working. If you have identical code which does something different, you will need to use your skills as a C# developer to debug it. If you have changed it, you will need to share what you're actually running.

Comment: suppose i am not calling this method in an async method and call it like this will it work -> var result = PingAsync(iPAddresses, 10).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); as it hangs when i try to do this

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz That depends on whether the thread you're calling it on has a  SynchronizationContext installed on it. If it does, then you'll be hitting the classic async deadlock condition. Don't mix sync and async code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223756/discussion-between-canton7-and-muhammad-waqas-aziz).